# C# Mutex Timespan explained to newbie

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I am completely new to Mutex.

I dont understand what this means:

> WaitOne(TimeSpan) Blocks the current thread until the current instance
>   receives a signal, using a TimeSpan to specify the time interval.
>   (Inherited from WaitHandle.)

E.g. if I use:

```
static void Main() 
{
   using(Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, appGuid))
   {
      if(!mutex.WaitOne(2000, false))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Instance already running");
         return;
      }

      GC.Collect();                
      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}
```

does it mean that once the line

```
if(!mutex.WaitOne(2000, false))
```

is fired, it waits 2 seconds before it checks if there is a lock on the thread
?

Comment: Do you realise that the documentation quote you've given is for a different method than for the code you've written?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, the boolean overload doesn't make any difference anyway.

Comment: Time parameter is used to define *timeout*, which is the maximum allowed to wait time. `WaitOne` will try to obtain ownership before timeout is expired, starting from "immediately when called" ^^

Comment: Well, that's pretty straight-forward here, you are getting this code completely wrong.  Pretty sure you already know that, asking for a manual is not a great way to get the answer you need.  Single-instance apps are already very well supported by the .NET Framework, don't make up your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the current thread will block either until someone calls `mutex.ReleaseMutex()` or the 2000ms timeout has passed. If the timeout is reached, the operation returns `false`.

More details on the method call are available in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN link.

So the bottom line is it doesn't matter what value you pass as a timeout, a call to `mutex.ReleaseMutex()` will immediately release the thread anyway - the timeout is there so that the call does not wait infinitely in case the mutex is never release or released at a period considered late by the application's circumstances.

Comment: so within the 2000ms that pass, does it try e.g. x amount if times to see whether the mutex is released?

Comment: Yes, something similar to that but this differs greatly depending on OS. Unfortunately I am not knowledgeable enough to tell you how Windows mutexes are implemented (.Net mutexes are simply wrappers to Windows mutexes), perhaps someone more keen on core Windows can help.